# Create table row on pressing Enter Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am creating a html table dynamically. Here for each row, two columns are created by a recursive call. Simply, when the second box is clicked, a new row is created and so on. But I want to replace the click with "Enter" key press. I tried, the code is working fine for creating new row by clicking, but not by hitting the Enter key.

```
  function CreateRow(){
    // Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
    var row = table.insertRow();

    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
/**    $(cell2).bind('click', function() {
        CreateRow();
    });
 */
$(cell2).keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        CreateRow();
    }
});


    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of binding a keydown event to a table cell, bind it to the document.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
```

Comment: And please add that that needs to be done outside of the function

Comment: It works. But , I need to bind another Enter key  event to column-1 cells. On clicking column-2 cells, they will create new row. Moreover, here the number of rows created are doubles up.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code here, we don't know how you are determining how the code knows which table to add rows to when the user hits enter.

Comment: This is my Table:<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="align_center" id="myTable">

        <tr id="noEdit" class="style_column_name">
            <td>DAY</td>
            <td>DOSE</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: There's no way you can localize the keydown event to a particular table cell, unless you have a text input. Think of it — when you press the Enter key, how does the browser know what cell are you looking at?

Comment: Click and keydown events are very different. Click events are triggered by a point device, which can exactly pinpoint where the user interaction is originating from. Keyboard events have no coordinates on the screen — unless, again, it's from a text input (textarea, input, select and etc).

Comment: @Terry Thanks a Ton. Got a solution in different approach. I am adding textFields to the cell and then binding the keydown there. Its working fine and my objective is done. :)